# UITableview for iphone programmers

Tags: iphone

I have UITableView.when i click on it's 1 st row one another UITableView opens and when i click on 2 nd row UIDatepicker opens.

my question is why my UIDatepicker and UITableview is not autoresizes though i set it's autoresize property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate way of setting up your application:

If you have your application set up with a navigation controller you could push your new views onto the view stack.  This would give your application the navigation bar and would give you a back button.  I don't think you would want to directly put your UITableView and UIDatePicker into a navigation controller but would instead want to create new view (using the new view template in Interface Builder) to put them in.

Comment: Thankyou very much for ur answer but u misinterpret my question

Comment: To be frank, the question was too ambiguous not to misinterpret.